# Leaflet Routing Machine: how to export route details and coordinates in JSON / GeoJSON?

Tags: leaflet, geojson, routing, json

I need to export / save the route details found using Leaflet Routing Machine in JSON or GeoJSON format.

I've tried to  use

```
var routeArray = new Array();
routeArray = control.getWaypoints();
alert (JSON.stringify(routeArray));
```

that works but in this manner I obtain only the waypoints and, instead,  I'm interested at ALL the route details (coordinates  and descriptions).

I guess that "somewhere" they are (in the picture when I put my mouse pointer on a description I can see a little blue circle on the map as you can see .... )

[image]

Any suggestion, example, jsfiddle to help me?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can access the instructions (that is, the turns etc.) by attaching a listener to your `Routing.Control` for a `routeselected` event. This will return a `RouteSelectedEvent` with an [`IRoute` object](http://www.liedman.net/leaflet-routing-machine/api/#iroute) inside it.

The IRoute contains the coordinates of the route path and waypoints (as arrays of `L.LatLng` objects) as well as the routing instructions (as an array of [`IInstruction` objects](http://www.liedman.net/leaflet-routing-machine/api/#iinstruction)). Each IInstruction has all the direction types, roads, etc., which can be formatted into human-readable strings using [`L.Routing.Formatter`](http://www.liedman.net/leaflet-routing-machine/api/#l-routing-formatter), as well as the `index` value of the corresponding point in the `coordinates` array.

Bringing all this together, here's a fiddle that extracts the instruction points and adds them to the map:

http://fiddle.jshell.net/nathansnider/kLymv7vc/

Here's the event listener code:

```
control.on('routeselected', function(e) {
  var coord = e.route.coordinates;
  var instr = e.route.instructions;
  L.geoJson(getInstrGeoJson(instr,coord)).addTo(map);
});
```

where `getInstrGeoJson` is a function that formats the instructions and coordinates into a GeoJSON object:

```
function getInstrGeoJson(instr,coord) {
  var formatter = new L.Routing.Formatter();
  var instrPts = {
    type: "FeatureCollection",
    features: []
  };
  for (var i = 0; i < instr.length; ++i) {
    var g = {
      "type": "Point",
      "coordinates": [coord[instr[i].index].lng, coord[instr[i].index].lat]
    };
    var p = {
      "instruction": formatter.formatInstruction(instr[i])
    };
    instrPts.features.push({
      "geometry": g,
      "type": "Feature",
      "properties": p
    });
  }
  return instrPts
}
```

The Leaflet.Routing.Machine author has also written [some routines](https://github.com/perliedman/leaflet-routing-machine/blob/344ff09c8bb94d4e42fa583286d95396d8227c65/src/L.Routing.js) for exporting the routes and waypoints as GeoJSON ([discussed here](https://github.com/perliedman/leaflet-routing-machine/issues/17#issuecomment-198270151)). Combining these with the code above, you could get GeoJSON for all the features that the routing machine produces.