# Extracting an encoded linestring from a website

Tags: web-mapping

I need to extract this highway route on this webpage. 
https://scenicbyways.info/byway/80452.html
web scraping is not part of my skill repertoire. Sometimes I add .geojson to the end of map link and it returns the geometry and attributes which i then scrape with python. however that is not the case here. I DO NOT want to manually create this.

https://scenicbyways.info/byway/80452.html

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can decode the polyline using

https://google-developers.appspot.com/maps/documentation/utilities/polylineutility_5bbd4b6fcb5fada7a7a2df3ef50d3f67.frame?hl=en

This provides all the coordinates you need

The encode polyline you requested is

> gzlwFpipiMqE{|@cDaU}Oio@wQoi@aMo_@oWcbA_Kg]cSca@_QqZwI}VmZacAgU{n@gPiWyFcJ{HcZkY{iAqh@yuBaOqk@aHyWmFu^m[mbCmIgr@_CyYcB{MoBsGqHs`AoHq{@uEo_@w_@ueBaGkNoLeJcJyEgKEkFyEqHiRuFoXaLoVeMuTwJsReCcPEaRkE_NeRye@oPmUuPqJmJ{IsIy`@eIkMiV{g@aKc]iFsNob@y]sYqT_HiIiY_H{JeHsN_Y_IgQ

Broken down you get the locations (waypoints)

> (40.70324,-75.12745) Level: 3(40.70429,-75.11755) Level: 3(40.70511,-75.11402) Level: 3(40.70782,-75.10629) Level: 3(40.71082,-75.09949) Level: 3(40.71307,-75.09429) Level: 3(40.71699,-75.08355) Level: 3(40.71891,-75.07871) Level: 3(40.72213,-75.07325) Level: 3(40.72501,-75.06884) Level: 3(40.72673,-75.06501) Level: 3(40.73112,-75.05412) Level: 3(40.73468,-75.04646) Level: 3(40.73744,-75.04257) Level: 3(40.73869,-75.04079) Level: 3(40.74027,-75.03645) Level: 3(40.74449,-75.02447) Level: 3(40.75114,-75.00546) Level: 3(40.75371,-74.99833) Level: 3(40.75516,-74.99436) Level: 3(40.75635,-74.98929) Level: 3(40.76090,-74.96826) Level: 3(40.76257,-74.96006) Level: 3(40.76321,-74.95577) Level: 3(40.76371,-74.95339) Level: 3(40.76427,-74.95201) Level: 3(40.76580,-74.94151) Level: 3(40.76732,-74.93182) Level: 3(40.76839,-74.92662) Level: 3(40.77363,-74.91019) Level: 3(40.77492,-74.90773) Level: 3(40.77708,-74.90594) Level: 3(40.77886,-74.90485) Level: 3(40.78082,-74.90482) Level: 3(40.78200,-74.90373) Level: 3(40.78353,-74.90064) Level: 3(40.78476,-74.89656) Level: 3(40.78685,-74.89280) Level: 3(40.78912,-74.88933) Level: 3(40.79100,-74.88619) Level: 3(40.79167,-74.88345) Level: 3(40.79170,-74.88040) Level: 3(40.79272,-74.87800) Level: 3(40.79579,-74.87179) Level: 3(40.79859,-74.86820) Level: 3(40.80142,-74.86635) Level: 3(40.80325,-74.86461) Level: 3(40.80495,-74.85920) Level: 3(40.80658,-74.85690) Level: 3(40.81031,-74.85036) Level: 3(40.83090,-74.83010) Level: 3(40.81224,-74.84554) Level: 3(40.81341,-74.84304) Level: 3(40.81909,-74.83811) Level: 3(40.82335,-74.83466) Level: 3(40.82479,-74.83301) Level: 3(40.82900,-74.83157) Level: 3(40.83340,-74.82594) Level: 3(40.83500,-74.82302) Level: 3

[image]

[image]

Note:
An encoded polyline is used for many reasons like to compress data (for web delivery) You can do encoding in postgis too https://postgis.net/docs/ST_AsEncodedPolyline.html

Comment: how did you obtain this? gzlwFpipiMqE{|@cDaU}Oio@wQoi@aMo_@oWcbA_Kg]cSca@_QqZwI}VmZacAgU{n@gPiWyFcJ{HcZkY{iAqh@yuBaOqk@aHyWmFu^m[mbCmIgr@_CyYcB{MoBsGqHsAoHq{@uEo_@w_@ueBaGkNoLeJcJyEgKEkFyEqHiRuFoXaLoVeMuTwJsReCcPEaRkE_NeRye@oPmUuPqJmJ{IsIy@eIkMiV{g@aKc]iFsNob@y]sYqT_HiIiY_H{JeHsN_Y_IgQ

Comment: @ziggy added screenshot. In Firefox (firebug plugin) you can see the response of the servers with the encoded polyline

Comment: okay I have google chrome!! any chance you know how to find it there? im looking through every link

Comment: > view-source:https://trips.furkot.com/widget/byway/80452 in chrome or use the developer tools

Comment: ahh got it, wow! so why is this polyline not freely available? and how did you copy out all the waypoint locations? it seems i can only click one at a time

Comment: it just an encoded polyline google do this for many reasons many to compress data. you can do encoding in postgis too https://postgis.net/docs/ST_AsEncodedPolyline.html

Comment: awesome! add the postgis example and I'll except the answer

Comment: i used this and it worked perfect 
create table warren_heritage_scenic_byway as 
select ST_LineFromEncodedPolyline('gzlwFpipiMqE{|@cDaU}Oio@wQoi@aMo_@oWcbA_Kg]cSca@_QqZwI}VmZacAgU{n@gPiWyFcJ{HcZkY{iAqh@yuBaOqk@aHyWmFu^m[mbCmIgr@
_CyYcB{MoBsGqHsAoHq{@uEo_@w_@ueBaGkNoLeJcJyEgKEkFyEqHiRuFoXaLoVeMuTwJsReCcPEaRkE_NeRye@oPmUuPqJmJ{IsIy@eIkMiV{g@aKc]iFsNob@y]sYqT_HiIiY_H{JeHsN_Y_IgQ');

Comment: You can get the coordinates from the encoded polyline with a little PostGIS sql. For example: SELECT  ST_AsEWKT(ST_FlipCoordinates(ST_AsEWKT(ST_LineFromEncodedPolyline('gzlwFpipiMqE{|@cDaU}Oio@wQoi@aMo_@oWcbA_Kg]cSca@_QqZwI}VmZacAgU{n@gPiWyFcJ{HcZkY{iAqh@yuBaOqk@aHyWmFu^m[mbCmIgr@_CyYcB{MoBsGqHs`AoHq{@uEo_@w_@ueBaGkNoLeJcJyEgKEkFyEqHiRuFoXaLoVeMuTwJsReCcPEaRkE_NeRye@oPmUuPqJmJ{IsIy`@eIkMiV{g@aKc]iFsNob@y]sYqT_HiIiY_H{JeHsN_Y_IgQ'))));   The pgAdmin4 tool makes it nice to work with a PostGIS enabled database.

Comment: what about this one? https://www.rivers.gov/rivers/musconetcong.php i cant find the polyline there

Comment: Post a different question please > it is json not encoded.

Comment: okay i will right now

Answer (score 0):

From the Website:
https://trips.furkot.com/byway/80452

```
    "name": "Warren Heritage Scenic Byway",
    "coordinates": {
        "lat": 40.70324223307528,
        "lon": -75.12743398187412
    },
    "custom": false,
    "visit_duration": 0
},
{
    "name": "Warren Heritage Scenic Byway - end",
    "coordinates": {
        "lat": 40.835,
        "lon": -74.82302
    },
```

The page plots a route over a google map. To do that it just uses start coordinates
and an ending coordinates, it has an encripted polyline it then displays. 
So the trick is to take the start and ending coordinates into something you can route against. 
I like Leaflet and would use the Leaflet Routing Machine and feed it the coordinates. 
Then using some additional JavaScript I would capture the route as JSON or GeoJSON.

Leaflet Routing Machine
http://www.liedman.net/leaflet-routing-machine/

How to convert route in laeflet to GeoJSON
[Leaflet Routing Machine: how to export route details and coordinates in JSON / GeoJSON?](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/186757/leaflet-routing-machine-how-to-export-route-details-and-coordinates-in-json-g)

**BUT:**

The pages says it's New Jersey rt57. So why not download the GIS data from the state and 
just select that route segment in your desktop GIS?
http://www.state.nj.us/transportation/gis/data.shtm

Comment: a few things 1. where were you able to find that geojson of the start and end points? 2. i barely know javascript, is there another way to do this? im competent in postgis and python 3. i know I can do it manually but I would like to be able to figure it out without manually doing this

Comment: Go to: https://trips.furkot.com/byway/80452 right-click/view source, at the bottom of the page. You could also copy/paste the page into http://jsbeautifier.org/ to make it easier to read.  To create the route you need a road source and you pass it the start/end points, it calculates the shortest path. Google/OSM/Mapquest are a few available as road sources. I'm not sure where to find a python web map source to use.

Answer (score 0):

As stated in [about](https://scenicbyways.info/about.html) section [scenicbyways.info](https://scenicbyways.info) its source code is available on [github](https://github.com/melitele/byways).

The byway you are looking for is here:
https://github.com/melitele/byways/blob/master/contents/byway/80452.md